# Android Converter, More Than 2 Units Per Conversion Type

Tags: android

So I'm fairly new to Android Development and Programming in general... I have a working converter with a fatal flaw, per conversion type (Temp, Area, etc.) it can only use 2 units (Yards to Meters and Meters to Yards for example). This is limited by a radioGroup that would get miserably inefficient within the code and be painstaking for the user to find the right conversion. So I want to move from the radioGroup and button way to a more efficient spinner one. In which on one spinner the user chooses what to convert from and then on the other what to convert to. How would I accomplish this without writing the code for each different unit while still using spinners to choose what to convert to,

```
private float convertSYardsToSMeters(float syards) {
    return (float) (syards * .83613);
}
```

Thanks in advance... Sorry if this is a bit much just kind of confused.

Comment: can you explain what you mean by "without writing the code for each different unit.."? I think you will need some code to perform the conversions for each unit.

Comment: Well yes obviously but i mean with this kind of code for each thing  private float convertSYardsToSMeters(float syards) {
    return (float) (syards * .83613);
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still need to write the method `how units are converted`. With the Spinner you can only make the choosing from what to want unit to convert looks fancier, I dont know if the Spinner has something to ease the conversion. And based on choice from the spinner you apply method of conversion . Does it makes sense to you?

Comment: So write to a string file and reference that, and have a base unit on what to do the math with, and have corresponding values for each. For the ease of conversion so the user doesnt have to scroll down a huge list like Fahrenheit to celc and celc to fahr then kel to fahr and kel to cel

Comment: I understand your idea. And let me tell you my idea as an addition of yours. So you have 2 spinners. With one you choose what are you trying to convert. Example, I want to convert 18 liters into x unit. When I select liters the second spinner is fed with all the possible conversion units for measuring liquids. Like this you are limiting the scrolling. In the second spinner you have ONLY the POSSIBLE. I hope you get my idea.

Comment: Exactly, but Im not quite sure how to implement it, so looks like i will be looking around for a while.

Comment: It's a matter of if and else. First make some rough version, then try to optimize how one action can affect the other.

Comment: Just follow the pattern you have in mind `Choosing type -> Choosing one unit -> Showing "TO-WHICH" possible units -> Showing result.`

Comment: Idea for implementing: Make resources let say that contain meters, yards, furlongs etc and if meters is chosen you display the same resource of units beside the chosen one. Make a use of 2-d Arrays or Maps...I gave you all my ideas, I think :D

Comment: I think I got it now to modify what I have to get MUCH bigger and work exactly how I want it, thx for the help :D